# Improving a search query

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a query for search function.

Basically search function allowed user to define what they "have" and "want". Then this query will filter out all the possible result which created by other user.

For example, I have apple (with good quality) and I want orange (with poor quality). So the result will display all user that have orange (with poor quality) and want apple (with good quality).

The search query a bit long and i try to simplify as below:

This stored procedure will receive user defined table (ItemID & Quality) as parameters

```
@WantUdt AS HaveItemUdt READONLY,
@HaveUdt AS HaveItemUdt READONLY
```

Search query (user can define more than one items and quality, so i use `IN`):

```
SELECT * from tbl_Trade WHERE TradeID IN

 (SELECT TradeID from tbl_Want w INNER JOIN

  (SELECT TradeID FROM tbl_Have 
  WHERE HaveID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM @HaveUdt) AND 
  Quality IN (SELECT QualityID FROM @HaveUdt)) as h  --to filter [have], 

 ON w.TradeID = h.TradeID

  WHERE WantID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM @WantUdt) AND 
  Quality =IN (SELECT QualityID FROM @WantUdt)    --to filter [want]
)
```

Above query work as expected. However, I am having performance issue. I try do stress test by execute this stored procedure for multiple times within specific time (few seconds), and my db (SQL Server 2008 Express) seems can't effort and generate a timeout error

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I guess it is because the query above use too many IN CLAUSE.

Is there any way to improve this query?

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing the table structures or having sample data. Please consider sharing an SQLFiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with your tables, some representative data and your query to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this. I hope it will help.

SELECT * -- select only those columns which are required
FROM  tbl_Trade AS tt (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN tbl_Want w(NOLOCK) ON tt.TradeId = w.TradeID
INNER JOIN tbl_Have  h (NOLOCK) ON h.TradeID = w.TradeID
INNER JOIN @HaveUdt hu(NOLOCK) ON hu.itemId = h.HaveID AND hu.QualityId = h.Quality
INNER JOIN @WantUdt wu (NOLOCK) ON wu.ItemId = w.WantID AND wu.QualityId = w.Quality

Thanks
```